# Is it smart to replace boost::thread and boost::mutex with c++11 equivalents?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, mutex

Motivation:  reason why I'm considering it is that my genius project manager thinks that boost is another dependency and that it is horrible because "you depend on it"(I tried explaining the quality of boost, then gave up after some time :( ). Smaller reason why I would like to do it is that I would like to learn c++11 features, because people will start writing code in it.
So:

1. Is there a 1:1 mapping between `#include<thread> #include<mutex>`and
   boost equivalents?
2. Would you consider a good idea to replace boost stuff with c++11
   stuff. My usage is primitive, but are there examples when std doesnt
   offer what boost does? Or (blasphemy) vice versa?

P.S. 
I use GCC so headers are there.

Comment: Your project manager is not alone in partially or completely banning boost.  From Google coding guidelines: "Some Boost libraries encourage coding practices which can hamper readability, such as metaprogramming and other advanced template techniques, and an excessively "functional" style of programming."

Comment: IMO Google coding guidelines are stupid in many ways... For eg. they dont allow auto from C++11... :)

Comment: Quoting guidelines: [auto] hampers readability [because it removes] checked redundancy (such as type names) that may be helpful to readers.

Comment: for ( auto it=v.begin()... :)

Comment: ? Yes, so the point is that the reader now needs to know the type of "v" to figure out what the type of "it" is.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: Really? Personally I don't think I've ever cared about the actual type of the iterator (well maybe a few times), only the supported operations... I would argue that syntactical redundancy is rarely a good think (DRY).

Comment: @Grizzly: You don't care about the type of the iterator if you know what the type of v is, as the writer does, however the reader may not have v's declaration handy (maybe it is member variable for example), but if iterator was explicitly declared he could see it.  If you Don't Repeat Yourself you only have to say something wrong once to create a bug, and people listening to you better be listening careful for you shall say things only once.  (Why do airline attendants "crosscheck"?)  The time taken to type in code is *NOT* the bottleneck in software development.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: Not hust when I have the containers declaration handy. In general when iterating over a container I do **not** care at all about the type of the container. Often enough I don't even care about the contained type, only about the operations possible on that (which is often clear from the code using it). Mentioning the complete type of long type expressions (iterators, smartpointer) only makes the code less compact and therefore less readable (I don't want to read all that) and harder to change  while adding little to no value. So I stand by my statement.

Comment: @Grizzly: I've noted that people that spend a lot of time working on small projects that they write themselves generally have that attitude, if you work on large codebases with teams of programmers you spend a lot of time reading/debugging code that you didn't write, so your tastes change.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: You are missing my point. I'm saying that I often don't care about the type when reading the code (mine or that of other developers). Not because I've written the code and know the type (chances are I didn't/don't), but simply because often enough it simply doesn't matter to the code. In those cases explicitely mentioning the type leads to more convoluted, which makes it harder to find the actual bugs in the code. This doesn't mean that types where it matters shouldn't be mentioned.

Comment: @Grizzly: The reason that knowing the type of variables is helpful is that without them you don't know which function is dispatched on an overload, operator or method call, so you cannot step in statically - either in your imagination or actually in your ide.  Many times this is key to understanding what is going on (or going wrong).  Further the name of the type gives clues about its intended semantics, and also lets you know where the variable memory layout is defined.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: I don't disagree that this can be helpful in some situations. However that isn't universely applicable: I don't think I want ever to step into a function in the standard library (well sometimes, but I usally regret it). So I usually don't care about the type of an iterator. I might care about the underlying type in some cases, so I might e.g. create a reference to the element pointed to by the iterator (compiler not supporting ranged for unfortunately), if that knowledge is necessary for understanding the code.

Comment: @Grizzly: So the point is `for (auto it=v.begin()...) it->foo();` - which function foo is called.

Comment: btw google modified its dumb guidelines so now finally they allow auto

Comment: @AndrewTomazos I feel `auto` is fine in cases like `auto foo = dynamic_cast<Foo*>(bar);` and other such situations where the result type is obvious from the supplied expression.

Comment: I don't think it's blasphemy to imply that Boost doesn't offer what std (the standard library) does. Boost is supposed to be complementary to std, and as such doesn't contain everything std does.

Comment: From Boost's web page: "_Ten Boost libraries are included in the C++ Standards Committee's Library Technical Report (TR1) and in the new C++11 Standard. C++11 also includes several more Boost libraries in addition to those from TR1. More Boost libraries are proposed for standardization in C++17._" So yes, there are stuff std doesn't offer that Boost offers. :)

Answer (score 195, accepted):

There are several differences between Boost.Thread and the C++11 standard thread library:

- Boost supports thread cancellation, C++11 threads do not
- C++11 supports `std::async`, but Boost does not
- Boost has a `boost::shared_mutex` for multiple-reader/single-writer locking. The analogous `std::shared_timed_mutex` is available only since C++14 ([N3891](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3891.htm)), while `std::shared_mutex` is available only since C++17 ([N4508](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4508.html)).
- C++11 timeouts are different to Boost timeouts (though this should soon change now Boost.Chrono has been accepted).
- Some of the names are different (e.g. `boost::unique_future` vs `std::future`)
- The argument-passing semantics of `std::thread` are different to `boost::thread` --- Boost uses `boost::bind`, which requires copyable arguments. `std::thread` allows move-only types such as `std::unique_ptr` to be passed as arguments. Due to the use of `boost::bind`, the semantics of placeholders such as `_1` in nested bind expressions can be different too.
- If you don't explicitly call `join()` or `detach()` then the `boost::thread` destructor and assignment operator will call `detach()` on the thread object being destroyed/assigned to. With a C++11 `std::thread` object, this will result in a call to `std::terminate()` and abort the application.

To clarify the point about move-only parameters, the following is valid C++11, and transfers the ownership of the `int` from the temporary `std::unique_ptr` to the parameter of `f1` when the new thread is started. However, if you use `boost::thread` then it won't work, as it uses `boost::bind` internally, and `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied. There is also a bug in the C++11 thread library provided with GCC that prevents this working, as it uses `std::bind` in the implementation there too.

```
void f1(std::unique_ptr<int>);
std::thread t1(f1,std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42)));
```

If you are using Boost then you can probably switch to C++11 threads relatively painlessly if your compiler supports it (e.g. recent versions of GCC on linux have a mostly-complete implementation of the C++11 thread library available in `-std=c++0x` mode).

If your compiler doesn't support C++11 threads then you may be able to get a third-party implementation such as [Just::Thread](http://www.stdthread.co.uk), but this is still a dependency.

Comment: Can you expand on the shared_mutex? I mean how can the mutex know if it is being locked by a reader or writer? I might have misunderstanding of what it does so my question is meaningless. Regarding Just::Thread I use it as documentation resource because it has nice list of the headers, but I use GCC so I have no need for temporary library(for eg. until MSVC doesnt implement all c++11 headers). Also can you please provide example for your last point, I'm a bit confused about it.

Comment: There are separate lock/unlock methods for readers and writers (`lock`/`unlock` for writers vs. 'lock_shared/unlock_shared' for readers).  Multiple readers can call lock_shared without blocking, as long as no writers are using it.

Comment: The `shared_mutex` docs are at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex. You either lock the mutex as shared or exclusive, and then use the corresponding unlock function. You can also use the RAII types to do this (`shared_lock` takes a shared read lock, and `lock_guard` and `unique_lock` take an exclusive lock). I've tried to clarify the point about move-only types.

Comment: One more minor thing that tripped me up: in boost, destructor of a running thread detaches it ( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.destructor ), while in C++, destructor of a running thread calls terminate() (FDIS 30.3.1.3)

Comment: In C++11, `try_scoped_lock` functionality is covered by `std::unique_lock`. There is a constructor that takes a mutex and `std::try_to_lock`, and will then call `try_lock()` on the mutex rather than `lock()`. See http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/mutex/unique_lock/try_lock_constructor.html

Comment: Actually thee seems to be boost async now.

Comment: Yes, Boost.Thread has become much closer to the C++11 standard since I wrote this, primarily due to the work of Vicente Botet.

Comment: Is the bug of using `std::bind` for `std::thread` arguments still there? Can someone link to a bug page somewhere?

Comment: standard should've included thread cancellation by now since boost already supports it.

Answer (score 24):

`std::thread` is largely modelled after `boost::thread`, with [a few differences](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2184.html):

> - boost's non-copyable, one-handle-maps-to-one-os-thread, semantics are retained. But this thread is movable to allow returning thread from factory functions and placing into containers.
> - This proposal adds cancellation to the `boost::thread`, which is a significant complication. This change has a large impact not only on thread but the rest of the C++ threading library as well. It is believed this large change is justifiable because of the benefit.
>
>   - The thread destructor must now call cancel prior to detaching to avoid accidently leaking child threads when parent threads are canceled.
>   - An explicit detach member is now required to enable detaching without canceling.
> - The concepts of thread handle and thread identity have been separated into two classes (they are the same class in `boost::thread`). This is to support easier manipulation and storage of thread identity.
> - The ability to create a thread id which is guaranteed to compare equal to no other joinable thread has been added (`boost::thread` does not have this). This is handy for code which wants to know if it is being executed by the same thread as a previous call (recursive mutexes are a concrete example).
> - There exists a "back door" to get the native thread handle so that clients can manipulate threads using the underlying OS if desired.

This is from 2007, so some points are no longer valid: `boost::thread` has a `native_handle` function now, and, as commenters point out, `std::thread` doesn't have cancellation anymore.

I could not find any significant differences between `boost::mutex` and `std::mutex`.

Comment: `std::thread` doesn't have cancellation; it is `boost::thread` that does!

Comment: @Anthony are you sure you don't mean `interrupt()` for boost::thread? Also it appears that it's an original proposal, which changed since 2007.

Comment: Yes, cancellation in boost is called "interruption". Yes, this is an old proposal. The latest public draft of the C++11 standard (which includes the thread library) is http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf

Answer (score 6):

**Enterprise Case**

If you are writing software for the enterprise that needs to run on a moderate to large variety of operating systems and consequently build with a variety of compilers and compiler versions (especially relatively old ones) on those operating systems, my suggestion is to stay away from C++11 altogether for now.  That means that you cannot use `std::thread`, and I would recommend using `boost::thread`.

**Basic / Tech Startup Case**

If you are writing for one or two operating systems, you know for sure that you will only ever need to build with a modern compiler that mostly supports C++11 (e.g. VS2015, GCC 5.3, Xcode 7), and you are not already dependent on the boost library, then `std::thread` could be a good option.

**My Experience**

I am personally partial to hardened, heavily used, highly compatible, highly consistent libraries such as boost versus a very modern alternative.  This is especially true for complicated programming subjects such as threading.  Also, I have long experienced great success with `boost::thread` (and boost in general) across a vast array of environments, compilers, threading models, etc.  When its my choice, I choose boost.

Comment: @UmNyobe He is right though. Many implementations of C++11 threading are so broken I am surprised people even consider using it.

Answer (score 5):

There is one reason not to migrate to `std::thread`.

If you are using static linking, `std::thread` becomes unusable due to these gcc bugs/features:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52590
- http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57740

Namely, if you call `std::thread::detach` or `std::thread::join` it will lead to either exception or crash, while `boost::thread` works ok in these cases.

Comment: I see that one bug is UNCONFIRMED and the other is INVALID, with a comment saying the reporter should have linked against `libpthread.a`. Are you absolutely sure in what you're saying?

Comment: @einpoklum, you should be able to make it work by using `Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive`, see this answer for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/23504509/72178. But it is not very straightforward way to link with `libpthread.a` and also considered bad idea.

Comment: Can we assume these bugs are fixed as this is now 2016?  The bugs were posted in 2012 and from gcc 4.9.2, it officially supports C++11 so we can't complain C++11 before the official support.

Answer (score 3):

With Visual Studio 2013 the `std::mutex` seems to behave differently than the `boost::mutex`, which caused me some problems (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27800412/487356)).

Answer (score 2):

## With regards to std::shared_mutex added in C++17

The other answers here provide a very good overview of the differences in general. However, there are several issues with `std::shared_mutex` that boost solves.

1. Upgradable mutices. These are absent from `std::thread`. They allow a reader to be upgraded to a writer *without allowing any other writers to get in before you*. These allow you to do things like pre-process a large computation (for example, reindexing a data structure) when in read mode, then upgrade to write to apply the reindex while only holding the write lock for a short time.
2. Fairness. If you have constant read activity with a `std::shared_mutex`, your writers will be softlocked indefinitely. This is because if another reader comes along, they will always be given priority. With `boost:shared_mutex`, all threads will *eventually* be given priority.<sup>(1)</sup> Neither readers nor writers will be starved.

The tl;dr of this is that if you have a very high-throughput system with no downtime and very high contention, `std::shared_mutex` will never work for you without manually building a priority system on top of it. `boost::shared_mutex` will work out of the box, although you might need to tinker with it in certain cases. I'd argue that `std::shared_mutex`'s behavior is a latent bug waiting to happen in most code that uses it.

<sup>(1)</sup> <sub>The [actual algorithm it uses](https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/develop/include/boost/thread/win32/shared_mutex.hpp) is based on the OS thread scheduler. In my experience, when reads are saturated, there are longer pauses (when obtaining a write lock) on Windows than on OSX/Linux.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use shared_ptr from std instead of boost and I actually found a bug in gcc implementation of this class. My application was crashing because of destructor called twice (this class should be thread-safe and shouldn't generate such problems). After moving to boost::shared_ptr all problems disappeared. Current implementations of C++11 are still not mature.

Boost has also more features. For example  header in std version doesn't provide serializer to a stream (i.e. cout << duration). Boost has many libraries that use its own ,  etc. equivalents, but do not cooperate with std versions.

To sum up - if you already have an application written using boost, it is safer to keep your code as it is instead of putting some effort in moving to C++11 standard.

Comment: The `shared_ptr` destructor doesn't need to be thread-safe, it's undefined behaviour to have one thread accessing an object while another thread is destroying it. If you think you've found a bug in GCC's shared_ptr please [report it](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/), otherwise on the balance of probability you're using it wrong.