# Is std::thread a drop in replacement for boost::thread?

Tags: c++, boost

I have a code base that is using many instances of detached `boost::thread` as folllows

```
boost::thread th( boost::bind(&myFunc,var1, var2 ));
```

Can I simply do a search replace and start using `std::thread`?

Do I need to replace `boost::bind` with `std::bind` too or that is unnecessary?

( I found I could do search replace `boost::shared_ptr` with `std::shared_ptr` and `boost::scoped_ptr` with `std::unique_ptr` so far without any issues.

My platform is Visual Studio 11 on Windows 7.

Comment: [You may be interested in this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241993/is-it-smart-to-replace-boostthread-and-boostmutex-with-c11-equivalents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I simply do a search replace and start using std::thread?

The current version of `boost::thread` has a few features that aren't in `std::thread`:

- join with timeout
- thread attributes
- interruption
- `yield()` and `sleep()` (deprecated)

See the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread), where they are labelled `EXTENSION`. If you're not using any of those, then it should be a direct replacement.

As mentioned in the comments, older versions of `boost::thread` had a different behaviour on destruction. They would detach the thread if it was still joinable; `std::thread` and the current `boost::thread` call `std::terminate` instead.

> Do I need to replace `boost::bind` with `std::bind` too or that is unnecessary?

That's not necessary; `thread` can be given any callable type. It's also not necessary to use `bind` at all, since it has a variadic constructor:

```
std::thread th(&myFunc, var1, var2);
```

Comment: Another difference is that `boost::thread`'s destructor just detaches, while `std::thread` requires an explicit call to `detach` or it will assert in the destructor.

Comment: @TravisGockel: That's true for older versions of Boost. The current version behaves like `std::thread` in this respect; see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.destructor)